# how to access python lists made with a for loop(reading data from a file)

Tags: python, arrays

i have made several arrays using a for loop by splitting lines from a text file. however, i do not know how to access the individual elements that these lists hold. i would prefer if someone showed me how to combine these arrays so the elements inside of them would be easier to access.

```
file2 = open('text_file.txt','r')
    for line in file2:
        words = line.split()
        words.remove(words[0])
        print(words)
```

Right now, that prints out this:

```
['CP', '0.50', '96']
['HR', '1.00', '93']
['HR', '1.00', '85']
['HR', '1.00', '99']
['CP', '0.75', '100']
['CP', '1.00', '94']
['HR', '1.00', '88']
['CP', '1.00', '92']
```

as you can see, it shows 8 separate lists. When I try to access the data stored in these arrays, using

```
words[0]
words[1]
```

or

```
words[2]
```

inside of the for loop, i get many values instead of just 1. these arrays have no names, so how can one access each individual number or string from these arrays. for example, when i try:

```
print(words[0])
```

i get the following:

```
CP
HR
HR
HR
CP
CP
HR
CP
```

however, when i do:

```
print(words[0])
```

i want to have this as the result:

```
CP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"inside of the for loop, i get many values instead of just 1"

of course you will, it is a loop, and the loop will run several times hence the many values.
what you need is to create another list of lists where you store your `words` and then access them from outside the loop:

```
file2 = open('text_file.txt','r')
lines = []
for line in file2:
    words = line.split()
    words.remove(words[0])
    lines.append(words)
print(lines[0][0]) # to print CP from the first line in the document
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that you only want to read the 1st line of the file, use

```
line=file2.readline()
words = line.split()
print(words[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

try accessing each array this way

```
words = [['CP', '0.50', '96'],
['HR', '1.00', '93'],
['HR', '1.00', '85'],
['HR', '1.00', '99'],
['CP', '0.75', '100'],
['CP', '1.00', '94'],
['HR', '1.00', '88'],
['CP', '1.00', '92']]

[x[0] for x in words]
```